# Organizing range of cells using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data about 400 rows in columns B through U. Column F is the one in where dates are posted. I need to have it where all the data is organized by column F, without messing up the rest of the cells adjoining it.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: What do you mean organized? Sort it is ascending order?

Comment: can you be a little more clear. From what I read, I think it's a simple sort on Column F (making sure your whole data range is selected), but I can't imagine it's that simple. Maybe post an example workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("F1").Sort key1:=Range("F1"), order1:=xlAscending
```

If you have some header rows that shouldn't sorted you'll need specify the complete Range to be sorted (e.g. `Range("B2:U10").Sort`...) instead. Replace order1 with xlDescending if you want it descending instead.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Don't save the file if it doesn't do what you want, and let us know.

Comment: If by organize you mean sort, yes. Just make sure to tweak the first Range if necessary.

Comment: Does any of this have to have a dim attached to it? I'm just asking before I go to work, since I don't have the code to test out in front of me yet.